# ¿ Cómo desactivar el doble click de un boton?

Tags: java, android, botón

Tengo la siguiente función para guardar datos en una base de datos, donde "GuardarDatos" es el método onClick de mi botón, pero quiero que deshabilite el botón después de clickar 1 vez en él, para evitar que guarde todo el rato, mi funcion es esta y pensaba que estaba hecho con lo de onclicklistener pero veo que no... :

```
public void GuardarDatos(View view) {

    int primero = Integer.parseInt(Primero1.getText().toString());
    finalizar =(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Guardar) ;

    BaseHelper baseHelper = new BaseHelper (this,"DEMODB",null,1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = baseHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    if(db!=null){

        ContentValues registronuevo = new ContentValues();

        registronuevo.put("Primero",primero);

        long i = db.insert("Notas",null,registronuevo);
        if ( i>0)
            Toast.makeText(this,"Puntuación guardada",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        finalizar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override   
            public void onClick(View v){
                onStop();  //Se supone que esto basta pero no. No funciona
            }
        });
    }

}
```

ACTUALIZ:

`finalizar = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Guardar);`

```
     finalizar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //ejecuta el método
                GuardarDatos(); // --> Aquí me obliga a pasarle algo , 
                               // pone : The method GuardarDatos(View) in the type Tiempoacabadobebe is not applicable for the arguments () 
                //Deshabilita el botón
                finalizar.setEnabled(false); 
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escribe esto:

```
finalizar.setEnabled(false);
```

Te recomiendo que lo hagas de esta manera:

```
ImageButton boton= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        boton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //ejecuta el método
                guardarDatos();
                //Deshabilita el botón
                boton.setEnabled(false); 
            }

        });
        return true;
    }
public void guardarDatos(){
//cosas que quieres que haga el botón al clickearlo
}
```

**Dónde** *boton* es el imagebutton, el tuyo se llama *finalizar*.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55444/discussion-on-answer-by-x4mp73r--como-desactivar-el-doble-click-de-un-boton).

Answer (score 1):

```
public void GuardarDatos(View view) {

int primero = Integer.parseInt(Primero1.getText().toString());
finalizar =(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Guardar) ;

BaseHelper baseHelper = new BaseHelper (this,"DEMODB",null,1);
SQLiteDatabase db = baseHelper.getWritableDatabase();

if(db!=null){

    ContentValues registronuevo = new ContentValues();

    registronuevo.put("Primero",primero);

    long i = db.insert("Notas",null,registronuevo);
    if ( i>0)
        Toast.makeText(this,"Puntuación guardada",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    finalizar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.finalizar); finalizar.setClickable(false);
} }
```

Ojo con el findViewById el que yo he puesto es un ejemplo no sé cual será el id de tu buttón, y también acá mucho ojo no sé si estás usando buttón o AppCompatButtón, si no mas recuerdo así se llama

Comment: Es una imageButton y ya tengo creado un findViewById el tuyo del final no sirve jaja pero voy a probar el setClickable

Comment: jajaj eso debe funcionar y si obtienes un error mandas una imagen.

Comment: El setClickable tampoco funciona... T.T En serio no voy a poder hacer algo tan fácil que ya hice? Lo que comentas es lo que yo quiero hacer pero lo de x4mp73r lo he hecho y nada...

Comment: Me pone esto: [2016-09-19 17:43:59 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8700 for debugger Pero a ese error no hago caso pues me va toda la app , solo es al intentar hacer eso

Comment: Agregadme a skype para hablar y no hacer esto un chat: rafaespada3

Answer (score 0):

Es importante asegurar que la referencia del botón a la que le asignaras el `listener` es la correcta,

```
finalizar = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Guardar);
```

para que funcione correctamente el clic y la instrucción para deshabilitar el botón al realizar el clic.

```
finalizar = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Guardar);
   finalizar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //ejecuta el método
                GuardarDatos(); 
                //Deshabilita el botón
                finalizar.setEnabled(false); 
            }
             return true;
        });
```

Comment: Gracias Elena, de todas formas me iban sin el return. Lo que pasaba era que en vez de declarar en el xml un ImageButton declaraba un ImageView ...... T.T

Answer (score 0):

Compañeros, esta solucion me la encontre en un foro anterior. Y es mas simple que la de setEnable(true/false), ya que en ocasiones es complicado capturar el view del button que se desea habilitar.

Declaracion de Varibles:

```
...
private static final long TIEMPO_MINIMO= 1000; // Minimo de espera para click
private long ultimoClick= 0; // Fecha del Ultimo click capturado
...
```

Y por ultimo ponemos estas 5 lineas donde queremos evitar el doble click:

```
// Evitar doble click boton
if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - ultimoClick < TIEMPO_MINIMO){
    return;
}
ultimoClick= SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
```

Por ejemplo yo lo pongo dentro del metodo onClick:

```
...
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Evitar doble click boton
        if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - ultimoClick < TIEMPO_MINIMO){
            return;
        }
        ultimoClick= SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
...
```

Comment: Demasiada cosa, el de setEnabled es lo más fácil pues es solo 1 instrucción y me ha funcionado, gracias de todas formas :D

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setEnable(false);
```

con esto es mas que suficiente para poder desactivar el clic en un button. :D